# unable to call C method with JNA from JAVA

Tags: java, jna, stringbuffer

hi i have this error and i don't know how fix.

the c code is

```
extern int APIENTRY LSGetDocData(short          hConnect,
                 HWND           hWnd,
                 unsigned long  *NrDoc,
                 LPSTR          FilenameFront,
                 LPSTR          FilenameBack,
                 LPSTR          Reserved1,      // not used must be NULL         LPSTR          Reserved2,      // not used must be NULL         LPHANDLE       *FrontImage,
                 LPHANDLE       *BackImage,
                 LPHANDLE       *Reserved3,     // not used must be NULL         LPHANDLE       *Reserved4,     // not used must be NULL         LPSTR          CodelineSW,
                 LPSTR          CodelineHW,
                 LPSTR          BarCode,
                 LPSTR          CodelinesOptical,
                 short          *DocToRead,
                 long           *NrPrinted,
                 LPVOID         Reserved5,      // not used must be NULL         LPVOID         Reserved6);
```

and my Java method is

```
public int LSGetDocData(short hConnect, int hWnd, long[] NrDoc, String FilenameFront, String FilenameBack, String Reserved1, String Reserved2, int[] FrontImage, int[] RearImage,
            int[] FrontImage2, int[] RearImage2, StringBuffer CodelineSW, StringBuffer CodelineHW, StringBuffer Barcode, StringBuffer CodelinesOptical, short[] DocToRead, long[] NrPrinted,
            int Reserved5, int Reserved6);



public int lSGetDocData(long[] nrDoc, int[] frontImage, int[] rearImage,StringBuffer micrHW, StringBuffer barcode,StringBuffer micrSW,StringBuffer codeLineOptical) {

        return LsApi.call.LSGetDocData(hConnect[0], hWnd, nrDoc, "imageF", "ImageR", null, null, frontImage, rearImage, null, null, micrSW, micrHW, barcode, codeLineOptical, new short[0], new long[0], 0, 0);
    }
```

the error is

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unsupported argument type
>   java.lang.StringBuffer at parameter 11 of function LSGetDocData

i try  transform StringBuffer to String - Char - Pointer - Memory and the app show this error

```
invalid access memory
```

so if anyone know how transform StringBuffer to ?? 
I'll be eternally grateful
thanks in advance

Comment: also can anyone tell me how to modify the LPSTR funct with a function to  JNA

Comment: Native `long` != Java `long`.  On windows, native `long` is always 32 bits; Java `long` is 64 bits.

Comment: See also the FAQ on [reading back a string result](https://github.com/twall/jna/blob/master/www/FrequentlyAskedQuestions.md#how-do-i-read-back-a-functions-string-result) (you don't use a StringBuffer).

Comment: how fix the problem? i change lpstr for byte[]{256}

Comment: Use `byte[]`/`Native.toString(byte[])` or `char[]`/`Native.toString(char[])` where you need to pass a buffer as opposed to a string constant.

Comment: did you manage to solve this problem ?